# SQL Efficiency and speed

Tags: php, sql, performance

I have to delete records that contain the id in an array.

I just don't know which is better to use. Which is faster and more efficient?

**code 1**

```
$array = array('123','456','789' ...)//over 900 entries
$id = implode(',', $array);
$sql = 'DELETE FROM email WHERE id IN ('.$id.')';
//execute sql
```

or

**code2**

```
$array = array('123','456','789' ...)//over 900 entries
for($x=0;$x<count($array);$x++){
  $sql='DELETE FROM email WHERE id = '.$array[$x].' ';
  //execute sql
}
```

Which from the two is faster and more efficient when executed?

Comment: as of now i can't try it because i am currently working on a live database so.. once there will be a slow query that will be affecting calls that are currently ongoing. So i have to decide which one is better before i execute.

Comment: Restore one of your backup dumps to a test environment that you should already have.

Comment: You have not told which database system and client library this is. What you outline here can be very different depending on those and the actual processing. I also invite you to make use of the search on this website, because there are many insightful questions and answers regarding the (broad) topic of your question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Case 1 will be faster.

It is not only executing time of the query that determines the total amount of time. *Parsing, preparing* and *planning* also take time. In case 2 that needs to be done several times, in case 1 only once. Deleting a row will be equally fast, but it is the query overhead that makes case 1 faster.

Comment: the parsing and prepping argument would be mitigated by using prepared queries for the repeated query in the looped option. But even then I would still say the `in(..)` option is better.

Comment: Thanks! i'll stick to case 1 then!

Answer (score 1):

First one yields better performance. because for the second query if the record has 1000 rows, then web app has to hit the DB 1000 times for each deleting and the transaction log has to be updated for each transaction. So with that being said, option 1 is compartively better.